# Multiple values in session

Tags: php

I have three text boxes named as phoneno 1, 2, 3. I want get through session and stored in one value. If I echo stored value the three values of txt boxes should echo'd. How to do this?

```
$_SESSION['pno1'] = $_POST['pno1'];
$_SESSION['pno2'] = $_POST['pno2'];
$_SESSION['pno3'] = $_POST['pno3'];
$_SESSION['ext'] = $_POST['ext'];
```

I mean these all values are stored in $phonenumer how do.

Answer (score 2):

Its very unclear what you're asking. I will take a stab at it:

You had a form, you've entered a phone number in 3 text boxes
You have the variables pno1, 2 and 3.

You now want a phone_number variable, and to store that in the session.

how about

```
$_SESSION['phone_number']=$_SESSION['pno1']." ".$_SESSION['pno2']." ".$_SESSION['pno3']." (".$_SESSION['ext'].")";
```

Is this what you've asked?